# What are some resources for learning to write specifications?

Tags: specifications

At work I am responsible for writing specifications quite often and I am also the person who insisted on getting specifications in the first place. The problem is I am unsure how specifications should look and what they should contain. A lot of the time when my boss is writing the specifications (we are both inexperienced in it) they put in table names and things that I don't think belong there. So what is a good way to learn to write a good spec?

EDIT: Should a functional spec include things like assuming I am specifying a web application, the input types (a textbox, dropdown list, etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most important part of development documentation in my opinion, is **having the correct person do it.**

- Requirements Docs - Users + Business Analyst
- Functional Spec - Business Analyst + developer
- Technical Spec (how the functionality will actually be implemented) - Sr. Developer /
  Architect
- Time estimates for scheduling purposes - The **specific developer** assigned to the task

Having anyone besides the Sr. Developer / Architect define table structures / interfaces etc. is an exercise in futility - as the more experienced developer will generally throw most of it out.

Wikipedia is actually a good start for the Functional Spec, which seems similar to your Spec - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_specification.

Comment: What is the difference between a Functional spec and a Technical Spec?  My current workplace just has Requirement Documents and Specification Documents, and we have also had confusion about what should be included in the Spec doc. Thanks.

Comment: It's mostly just a protocol difference, a Functional spec can be a more concise description of the Requirements without getting into too much technical detail - but generally speaking the less documentation you can get away with before the developer is involved the better.

Ok, I'm biased. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's a great chapter in Steve McConnell's [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) that runs through specification documents and what they should contain.

When I was tasked to build an Architecture and Business Analysis team at a company that had never had either, I used McConnell's spec chapter to create the outline for the Technical Specification document.  It evolved over time, but by starting out with this framework I made sure we didn't miss anything and it turned out to be surprisingly usable.

When writing specs, a rule of thumb I follow is to try to have technical documents always start from the general and move to the specific -- always restate the business problem(s) or goal(s) that the technical solution is being developed to solve, so the person reading the spec doesn't need to go to other documents to put it in any sort of context.

Comment: Geez, that is a great book, along with Writing Solid Code. - Ron

Answer (score 2):

See [Painless Functional Specs](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html) by Joel Spolsky.

Some of the things he says every spec should have:

- A disclaimer
- An author. One author
- Scenarios
- Nongoals
- An Overview
- Details, details, details
- Open Issues
- Side notes

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to get something written down rather than worry about the format.

Comment: Trust me, I am very happy to have something down, which took me about a year to accomplish, I am not trying to refine the process.

Answer (score 1):

Buy Books:
Requirements Engineering by Ian Sommerville & Pete Sawyer ISBN 0-471-97444-7
or
Software Requirements by Karl Wiegers ISBN 0-7356-0631-5